# Filter out unrelated nodes in directed Graphviz graph?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have produced a digraph using Graphviz and `dot` that contains only one-way edges.  I would like to know a way to reduce the nodes and edges to only those nodes and edges that a specified node requires.  For example, given this dot file:

```
A->B
B->C
C->D
```

I would like a shell command that would focus on node B such that the resulting output looks like this:

```
B->C
C->D
```

For reference, I am using this as part of a project that converts a list of application dependencies in json into dot, and would like to be able to focus on a single application's dependencies when producing the graph.

Comment: I guess you mean that the resulting file is `A->B; B->C`. The sample yo9u give seems to concentrate on node `C`. Or am I not understanding your point?

Comment: Sorry, looked again and got it...

Comment: Try [gvpr](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gvpr)